# How do I make a collapsing toolbar always be positioned above a also collapsing ImageView while both are collapsing?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Tried to make a collapsing toolbar in android, but the toolbar always seems to overlap the imageview.
I want the toolbar to be on top of the imageview but it is always positioned in the same place, blocking the image.

This is the attempted main xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/img_5"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar2" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/Theme.ActuallyLab4"/>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include
        layout="@layout/content_main"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

which would output

[image: before scrolling down]

[image: while scrolling down]

[image: fully collapsed]

The purple toolbar is covering the image.

How do I edit the xml or code such that the purple toolbar will be positioned above the imageview until it results in the fully collapsed position?

Manifest if required:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ActuallyLab4"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.ActuallyLab4">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```